# Keyframes Parameters with SASS

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

I have created a rotating carousel in CSS, which I'm pretty happy with. It's included in the snippet. The original is on [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/CobusKruger/pen/WKzVqa).

It basically rotates the positions of four boxes. The total animation time is 8 seconds and I've set it up so it remains static for 20% of that, then moves the boxes for 5% and then waits again (run the snippet; I don't think I've explained it very well).

Now I want to parameterise it. Sass is my weapon of choice, and I can easily set up a few variables that would help. So right at the top of my styles, I have this:

```
$delays: 0s, -6s, -4s, -2s;
$fullanimtime: 8s;
$animationstops: 0%, 20%, 25%, 45%, 50%, 70%, 75%, 95%, 100%;
```

I use `$fullanimtime` as my `animation-duration`, and use the `$delays` list to configure the delays on my `pos-XXXX` styles:

```
.pos-1 {
  animation-delay: nth($delays, 1);
}
.pos-2 {
  animation-delay: nth($delays, 2);
}
.pos-3 {
  animation-delay: nth($delays, 3);
}
.pos-4 {
  animation-delay: nth($delays, 4);
}
```

This works like a charm, and by setting up `$fullanimtime` and `$delays` correctly, I can change the animation to run correctly for any time, be it 8 seconds, or 120 seconds.

The problem is that `@keyframes` use percentages. So if I set the other variables for a long animation time, the actual transitions that move the boxes get real slow: For 8 seconds, the transition runs for 400 ms, but for 120 seconds, they take 6 seconds, which is more annoying than cool.

So the `$animationstops` variable is supposed to let me configure reasonable timing. But that doesn't work.

For reasons I don't understand, I can't use the Sass `nth` function in a keyframe declaration, neither can I use a Sass variable.

```
@keyframes rotate-board {
  nth($animationstops, 1) {
    // This gives an error:
    // Invalid CSS after "nth": expected keyframes selector, was "($animationstop..."
  }
  $somevariable {
    // This gives an error:
    // Invalid CSS after " $somevalue ": expected ":", was "{"
  }
}
```

Is there a way around this, or have I found a limitation of Sass? And is there another pre-processor that I should use instead if I want to do this?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.frame {
  height: 580px;
  width: 100vw;
  background: lightgrey;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  width: calc(50% - 30px);
  height: calc(50% - 30px);
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: rotate-board;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.redbox {
  background: red;
}
.greenbox {
  background: green;
}
.bluebox {
  background: blue;
}
.orangebox {
  background: orange;
}

@keyframes rotate-board {
  0% {
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: calc(50% + 10px);
    right: calc(50% + 10px);
  }
  20% {
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: calc(50% + 10px);
    right: calc(50% + 10px);
  }
  25% {
    top: 20px;
    left: calc(50% + 10px);
    bottom: calc(50% + 10px);
    right: 20px;
  }
  45% {
    top: 20px;
    left: calc(50% + 10px);
    bottom: calc(50% + 10px);
    right: 20px;
  }
  50% {
    top: calc(50% + 10px);
    left: calc(50% + 10px);
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
  }
  70% {
    top: calc(50% + 10px);
    left: calc(50% + 10px);
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
  }
  75% {
    top: calc(50% + 10px);
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: calc(50% + 10px);
  }
  95% {
    top: calc(50% + 10px);
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: calc(50% + 10px);
  }
  100% {
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: calc(50% + 10px);
    right: calc(50% + 10px);
  }
}

.pos-1 {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.pos-2 {
  animation-delay: -6s;
}
.pos-3 {
  animation-delay: -4s;
}
.pos-4 {
  animation-delay: -2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="box redbox pos-1"></div>
  <div class="box greenbox pos-2"></div>
  <div class="box bluebox pos-3"></div>
  <div class="box orangebox pos-4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your variables like this:

```
#{nth($animationstops, 1)}
```

I created a Sassmeister for you:
https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/7c9b06c6b5a7cc580b14cbd1b312c566

Here it is at work: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PBeNLV

**PS**: Your animation is very beautiful! Congrats! :)

Comment: That's fantastic! Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome! :) And..., ok, this is only my opinion but... Stay with us writing Sass code without thinking of changing pre-processor 'cause SASS is fantastic!! :P Cheers. :)

Answer (score 1):

As ReSedano said, you can use the syntax `#{$var}` in order to resolve your problem.

You can also use the [loops provided from Sass](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while) in order to create a more readable code with less lines.

You can improve the final section of your code related to `pos-*` with the for loop, like the following code.

```
$delays: 0s, -6s, -4s, -2s;
@for $i from 1 through 4 {
  .pos-#{$i} {
    animation-delay: nth($delays, $i);
  }
}
```

You can also try to create a loop for the problem you are asking for. For example i found that there is a pattern like *aaaabbbb* that, with an offset for each side, can map your case in order to reproduce what you want. With this logic i have created the following code.

```
$animationPerc: 0%, 20%, 25%, 45%, 50%, 70%, 75%, 95%, 100%;
$animationPos: 20px, calc(50% + 10px);
$animationOffset: 0, 2, 4, 6; // top, left, bottom, right
@keyframes rotate-board {
  @for $i from 0 to 9 {
    #{nth($animationPerc, $i + 1)} {
      top: nth($animationPos, 1 + (floor((nth($animationOffset, 1) + $i)/4) % 2));
      left: nth($animationPos, 1 + (floor((nth($animationOffset, 2) + $i)/4) % 2));
      bottom: nth($animationPos, 1 + (floor((nth($animationOffset, 3) + $i)/4) % 2));
      right: nth($animationPos, 1 + (floor((nth($animationOffset, 4) + $i)/4) % 2));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant suggestion, thanks. It was actually on my radar, but I got stuck too soon.